# SensorManager: One SensorEventListener VS Multiple Listeners

Tags: android-sensors

I'm trying to log sensor measurements to the device memory. For this, I register the same SensorEventListener for many sensors, and later separate them using a switch, based on the type.

E.g.

```
int type = sensor.getType();

switch (type) {
    case Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER:
    // log accelerometer data
    break;

case Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE:
    // Log gyroscope data
    break;

...
```

My question is, what is the most efficient (less battery power consuming) way, having in mind that I registered the listener with SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST ? Having one listener for every sensor or having one listener and separating the sensors with a switch?

Thank you very much in advance

Minos

Comment: I think it doesn't matters, when all the sensors are active, their ADC produce data according to the time delay given (e.g SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST) so the battery consumption should remain same in both the case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A android application should use one **SensorEventListener** per Sensor as every SensorEventListener creates its **own FIFO buffer** to process the **SensorEvent**.
The consumption level of the current through the chip is related with the delay provided to the sensor **irrespective of the SensorEventListener** it is attached with.

If multiple sensors are used with one SensorEventListener than some events may get lost, due to **buffer overflow**, when the sensors are used at **SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST**.

So,For best results and to ensure that no event is lost:

- Use one SensorEventListener for one sensor.

  For increase in efficiency:
- when pausing the application, un-register all the sensor registered ,if they are not required, so they do not get events from the chip even after the application is closed.