# How to record data from several sensors in an android phone in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sensors, sensormanager

I know that you have to use this code to register your listener for you sensor, say, Accelerometer:

```
mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mAccelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
```

What if you want to record three sensors, for example? Will you edit the arguments of the code above and add other sensors you want to collect data from? Or enter similar lines of codes to this one, except you change the sensor?

Is the values stored in *events.values* array? If yes, how is the three triaxial sensors stored there? What is the size of this array?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SensorManager: One SensorEventListener VS Multiple Listeners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22816089/sensormanager-one-sensoreventlistener-vs-multiple-listeners)

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41859899/multiple-sensors-on-an-android-application